# How can I have mouse events received by an HTML element with lower z-index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm coding a checker game in JavaScript/JQuery. I have the following issue: I display the yellow arrows using a canvas that covers the entire screen and has z-index: 1. The checkers are z-index: 0.

I would like to add the possibility to drag and drop checkers. I want to use the [JQuery's draggable widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) to make every checker draggable. However, since the canvas has a higher z-index than the checkers, the latter won't receive the mouse events.

How can I have the checkers received the mouse events despite having a lower z-index?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't need mouseevents for your canvas, give `pointer-events:none;` a try. ([Relevant SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements))

Comment: This did the trick, thanks a lot! (I'll accept the answer in 9 min.)

Comment: Nice answer, however for reference, this is not supported in IE10 and below.